# Tomcat Digest unauthorized using C#

Tags: c#, authentication, tomcat, digest-authentication, unauthorized

The authentication is accepted and the results are fine, but at any time I add parameter to the URL in the same code, I get the error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I have tried several forms of Digest authentication but didn't solve the problem, here is some forms of the codes I user

```
CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
mycache.Add(uri, "Digest", new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin"));
req.Credentials = mycache;
```